# any limitation on JAVA REST API sendBatch emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, massemailmessage

If I use sendBatch to send multiple emails, is there a maximum number of emails limitation in the array?
Thanks.

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{your key}/sendBatch
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the Java API enforces any limitations on its own but you need to be coherent with the overall ExactTarget API guidelines which clearly state

- Keep your triggered send batches of Subscriber objects to numbers smaller than 100 for asynchronous calls and less than 50 for synchronous calls.
- Keep your maximum payload per call at less than 5MB.
- Pass less than 10 attributes to avoid decreased performances.

More information available [here](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/soap_api_best_practices/).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I saw this in the soap api. So it is the same limitation for rest api?